# Inverting a matrix using the LU decomposition

Tags: python, matrix, cython, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I have written the following `Matrix class` in **cython** for the matrix inversion and some other linear algebra operations. I tried to use the **LU decomposition**, in order to compute the inverse of a matrix. The speed of code is good. I tried to implement [this code](https://github.com/caioarruda/bCNC/blob/2cbfcc7944c01a9f0ad50b053464e1e04f716839/lib/bmath.py) in `cython`. I have checked every line of my code and compared with the given code couple of times but I still return wrong answer.

**matrix.pyx**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import cython
cimport cython  
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import ctypes                                             
from libc.math cimport log, exp, pow, fabs                                              
from libc.stdint cimport *
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libc.stdio cimport *
from libcpp cimport bool
cdef extern from "<iterator>" namespace "std" nogil:
    cdef cppclass iterator[Category, T, Distance, Pointer, Reference]:
        pass
    cdef cppclass output_iterator_tag:
        pass
    cdef cppclass input_iterator_tag:
        pass
    cdef cppclass forward_iterator_tag(input_iterator_tag):
        pass

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std" nogil:       
   void fill [ForwardIterator, T](ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator, T& )

cdef class Matrix:    
     def __cinit__(self, size_t rows=0, size_t columns=0, bint Identity=False, bint ones=False):
         self._rows=rows
         self._columns=columns
         self.matrix=new vector[double]()
         self.matrix.resize(rows*columns)

         if Identity:
            self._IdentityMatrix()

         if ones:
            self._fillWithOnes()

     def __dealloc__(self):
         del self.matrix

     property rows:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._rows
        def __set__(self, size_t x):
            self._rows = x    
     property columns:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._columns
        def __set__(self, size_t y):
            self._columns = y    

     cpdef double getVal(self, size_t r, size_t c):
           return self.matrix[0][r*self._columns+c]

     cpdef void setVal(self, size_t r, size_t c, double v): 
           self.matrix[0][r*self._columns+c] = v

     @cython.boundscheck(False)
     @cython.wraparound(False)
     cdef void _fillWithOnes(self):
          fill(self.matrix.begin(),self.matrix.end(),1.)

     cdef void _IdentityMatrix(self):
          cdef size_t i 
          if (self._rows!=self._columns):
             raise Exception('In order to generate identity matrix, the number of rows and columns must be equal')
          else:
             for i from 0 <= i <self._columns:
                 self.setVal(i,i,1.0)

     @cython.boundscheck(False)
     @cython.wraparound(False)
     cpdef Matrix Inv(self):               
           cdef Matrix A_inverse = Matrix(self._rows,self._columns)
           cdef MatrixList LU = ludcmp(self)
           cdef Matrix A    = LU.get(0)
           cdef Matrix indx = LU.get(1)
           cdef Matrix d    = LU.get(2)
           cdef double det  = d.getVal(0,0)
           cdef int i, j
           cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] L   = np.zeros((self._rows,self._columns),dtype=np.float64)
           cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] U   = np.zeros((self._rows,self._columns),dtype=np.float64)
           cdef Matrix col = Matrix(self._rows,1)
           for i from 0 <= i < self._rows: 
               for j from 0 <= j < self._columns:  
                   if (j>i):
                       U[i,j]=A.getVal(i,j)
                       L[i,j]=0
                   elif (j<i):
                       U[i,j]=0
                       L[i,j]=A.getVal(i,j)
                   else:
                      U[i,j]=A.getVal(i,j)
                      L[i,j]=1
           print "product of a lower triangular matrix L and an upper triangular matrix U:", np.dot(L, U)
           for i from 0 <= i < self._rows: 
               det*= A.getVal(i,i)
               for j from 0 <= j < self._columns:
                   if (i==j):
                      col.setVal(j,0,1)
               col=lubksb(A, indx, col)     
               for j from 0 <= j < self._columns:
                   A_inverse.setVal(j,i,col.getVal(j,0))
           print "determinant of matrix %.4f"%(det)
           return A_inverse

cdef class MatrixList:
     def __cinit__(self):
         self.inner = []

     cdef void append(self, Matrix a):
          self.inner.append(a)

     cdef Matrix get(self, int i):
          return <Matrix> self.inner[i]

     def __len__(self):
         return len(self.inner)


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)    
cdef Matrix lubksb(Matrix a, Matrix indx, Matrix b):
     cdef int n = a.rows
     cdef int i, ip, j
     cdef int ii = 0
     cdef double su
     for i from 0 <= i < n: 
         ip = <int>indx.getVal(i,0)
         su = b.getVal(ip,0)
         b.setVal(ip,0, b.getVal(i,0))
         if (ii):
             for j from ii <= j < (i-1): 
                 su -= a.getVal(i,j) * b.getVal(j,0)
         elif (su):
            ii = i       
         b.setVal(i, 0, su)
     for i from n > i >= 0: 
         su = b.getVal(i,0)
         for j from (i+1) <= j < n:
             su -= a.getVal(i,j) * b.getVal(j,0)
         b.setVal(i, 0, su/a.getVal(i,i))
     return b

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)    
cdef MatrixList ludcmp(Matrix a):
     #Given a matrix a_{nxn}, this routine replaces it by the LU decomposition of a row-wise permutation of itself.
     cdef MatrixList LU = MatrixList()
     cdef int n = a.rows
     cdef int i, j, k, imax
     cdef double big, dum, su, temp
     cdef Matrix vv   = Matrix(n,1)
     cdef Matrix indx = Matrix(n,1) #an output vector that records the row permutation effected by the partial pivoting
     cdef Matrix d    = Matrix(1,1, ones= True)  #an output as +1 or -1 depending on whether the number of row interchanges was even or odd, respectively
     cdef double TINY = 1.1e-16
     for i from 0 <= i < n: 
         big = 0.0
         for j from 0 <= j < n:
             temp=fabs(a.getVal(i,j))
             if (temp > big):
                big=temp
         if (big ==0.0):
             raise Exception("ERROR! ludcmp: Singular matrix\n")
         vv.setVal(i,0,1.0/big)

     for j from 0 <= j < n:
         for i from 0 <= i < j: 
             su = a.getVal(i,j)
             for k from 0 <= k < i:
                 su -= a.getVal(i,k)*a.getVal(k,j)
             a.setVal(i,j,su)

         big=0.0
         for i from j<= i< n:
             su = a.getVal(i,j)
             for k from 0 <= k < j:
                 su -= a.getVal(i,k)*a.getVal(k,j)
             a.setVal(i, j, su)
             dum=vv.getVal(i,0)*fabs(su )
             if (dum >= big):
                big=dum
                imax=i

         if (j != imax):
            for k from 0 <= k < n:
                dum = a.getVal(imax,k)
                a.setVal(imax, k, a.getVal(j,k))
                a.setVal(j,k, dum)
            d.setVal(0, 0, -d.getVal(0,0))
            vv.setVal(imax, 0, vv.getVal(j, 0))
         indx.setVal(j, 0, imax)
         if (a.getVal(j,j) == 0.0):
             a.setVal(j,j, TINY)
         if (j != (n-1)):
            dum=1.0/a.getVal(j,j)
            for i from (j+1)<= i <n:
                a.setVal(i,j, a.getVal(i,j)*dum)
     LU.append(<Matrix>a)
     LU.append(<Matrix>indx)
     LU.append(<Matrix>d)
     return LU
```

**matrix.pxd**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cdef class MatrixList:
     cdef list inner
     cdef void append(self, Matrix a)
     cdef Matrix get(self, int i)

cdef class Matrix:
     cdef vector[double] *matrix   
     cdef size_t _rows
     cdef size_t _columns
     cdef bint Identity
     cdef bint ones

     cpdef double getVal(self, size_t r, size_t c)
     cpdef void setVal(self, size_t r, size_t c, double v)
     cpdef Matrix transpose(self)
     cdef void _IdentityMatrix(self)
     cdef void _fillWithOnes(self)
     cpdef Matrix Inv(self)         
cdef Matrix lubksb(Matrix a, Matrix indx, Matrix b)    
cdef MatrixList ludcmp(Matrix a)
```

Any help to find the bug will be appreciated.

**example:**

```
import numpy
from matrix import Matrix
from numpy.linalg import inv
import timeit
import numpy as np
r=numpy.random.random((100, 100))
d=Matrix(r.shape[0],r.shape[1])
for i in range(d.rows):
     for j in range(d.columns):
         d.setVal(i,j,r[i,j])        


start = timeit.default_timer()
x=d.Inv()
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print "LU decomposition:", stop - start
```

Comment: I'm afraid this question is beyond me but: 1) it would help if you added the test-cases you were using; 2) `'MatrixList' object has no attribute 'inner'` (i.e. make sure the exact code you've posted actually runs)

Comment: @DavidW I updated my question.  `MatrixList` has attribute for `inner` in `__cinit__`.

Comment: Sorry yes I missed the pxd file so you're right about part 2.

Comment: @DavidW I am wondering whether there is way to parallelize the matrix inversion part? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know how myself. I'd focus on getting it to work first. I think you should take the `bmath` code that you linked and add a bunch of `print` statements, add the same `print`s in your Cython code and see if you can spot where they diverge. Start with really small (3x3?) matricies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that there are very small mistakes I made in the `lubksb` function and by fixing them I am getting the right answer. Here is the fixed code:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)    
cdef Matrix lubksb(Matrix a, Matrix indx, Matrix b):
     cdef int n = a.rows
     cdef int i, ip, j
     cdef int ii = 0
     cdef double su
     for i from 0 <= i < n: 
         ip = <int>indx.getVal(i,0)
         su = b.getVal(ip,0)
         b.setVal(ip,0, b.getVal(i,0))
         if (ii>=0):
             for j from ii <= j <= (i-1): 
                 su -= a.getVal(i,j) * b.getVal(j,0)
         elif (su):
            ii = i       
         b.setVal(i, 0, su)
     for i from n >= i >= 0: 
         su = b.getVal(i,0)
         for j from (i+1) <= j < n:
             su -= a.getVal(i,j) * b.getVal(j,0)
         if (a.getVal(i,i)==0.0):
             a.setVal(i,i, 1.1e-16)
         b.setVal(i, 0, su/a.getVal(i,i))
     return b
```